# Python subprocess - check exit codes of forked program

Tags: python, subprocess, fork

Say I have a script like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python forked_job.py'], shell=True)
status = p.wait()
# Do something with status
```

And then forked_job.py looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

print 'hi'
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    sys.exit(do_some_work())
else:
    sys.exit(do_other_work())
```

How can I make sure both processes return a 0 status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fork, you have a parent and a non-parent process.  When pid == 0, you are in the child process; your else statement is when you're within the parent process.

Similar to calling `Popen.wait`, as you do in the first script, you want to call `os.wait` in the second one.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

> **os.wait()**
>
> Wait for completion of a child process, and return a tuple
>   containing its pid and exit status indication: a 16-bit number, whose
>   low byte is the signal number that killed the process, and whose high
>   byte is the exit status (if the signal number is zero); the high bit
>   of the low byte is set if a core file was produced.
>
> Availability: Unix

As you can see, this of course assumes that you're running unix.  Since `os.fork` is also Unix-only, this seems likely.

So, have the parent call `os.wait` and reflect the status back up in what the parent returns.

One thing to note, though it probably doesn't matter, and you're probably aware.  You're technically not doing this:

```
    main_script
     /       \
forked_job   forked_job
```

But instead:

```
        main_script
            |
      forked_job_parent
            |
       forked_job_child
```

(I'm attempting to show the "ownership", and hence the usage of the second wait.)

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Follow up question.  What if the child finishes before the parent gets to os.wait?  How is the parent able to still get the exit status?

Comment: [man 3 wait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wait)  I hate to say it, but just treat it as magic. :-)  The whole concept of child processes is built to handle exactly what you're worried about.  wait will block for the child, or if the child is done, will automatically return with the status you need.  If you don't like "magic", just know that it's built into the kernel.  Which for most people, including me, comes out to the same thing.

Comment: Actually, this seems like a concise way of demystifying the magic: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/07/linux-process-life-cycle

Comment: Excellent thanks!  From your article, I guess this is the part that answers my question "An entry containing some information related to it is kept in the Kernel process address table till the parent process explicitly calls wait() or waitpid() functions to get the exit status of child process."

Comment: Yup.  And if you don't recover that information with `wait`, that's where [zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) come from.

Comment: I recommend using os.waitpid() to wait for that specific child; otherwise you may have race conditions, in which a part of your program may receive the exit status of a subprocess forked in another part of your program!